# Catch password expiry warning with OCCI

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface, occi

I am trying to find a way to "catch" (not in a strict C++ sense) the "ORA-28002: the password will expire within %s days" warning when connecting to the database.

I know that in OCI there is a SUCCESS_WITH_INFO status returned when opening the connection which contains the warning message, but what is a way to access this via OCCI?